# a div doesn't appear, it's not visible

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I have a problem, here is my code

Html and CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    src: url("font/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf") format('truetype');
}

.firstPage {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.box span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: -10px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -10px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px, 10px);
  }

}

.bigTitle {
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.Oswald {
  font-family: "Oswald";
}

.middleTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 43%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.rightTextHeader {
  margin-left: 3vh;
  margin-top: 1.5vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 8.5vh
}

.secondPage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Purpl5Rain - Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/firstPage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/secondPage.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <p class="Oswald rightTextHeader">BeatMaker</p>
    </div>
    <div class="firstPage">
      <div class="middleTitle">
        <h1 class="bigTitle Oswald">PURPL5RAIN</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondPage">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is : why secondPage doesn't appear on my website ?

I tried so many thing but nothing works, I need help, I didn't find help on internet

Sorry if my English is very bad I'm French and I don't speak English very well

Thanks for everybody who will help me.

Answer (score 1):

The background color of the `<div class="secondPage">` is black. That's the reason. As well as, you didn't add anything to your second page. Change the background color. I changed it to white and add some text. As your wish you can change the fonts colors and background color.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    src: url("font/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf") format('truetype');
}

.firstPage {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.box span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: -10px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -10px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px, 10px);
  }

}

.bigTitle {
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.Oswald {
  font-family: "Oswald";
}

.middleTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 43%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.rightTextHeader {
  margin-left: 3vh;
  margin-top: 1.5vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 8.5vh
}

.secondPage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Purpl5Rain - Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/firstPage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/secondPage.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <p class="Oswald rightTextHeader">BeatMaker</p>
    </div>
    <div class="firstPage">
      <div class="middleTitle">
        <h1 class="bigTitle Oswald">PURPL5RAIN</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondPage">
    <h1>Second Page</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background-color: #000` maybe the part of his style sheet. And you added a `h1` heading in the `.secondPage`, which he didn't. That's causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I added it to show him that it's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Oswald";
    src: url("font/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf") format('truetype');
}

.firstPage {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.box span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;
  border-right: 1.5px solid #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* also, I think you don't need this line since you are already transforming the rotate() property in @keyframes animate */
  margin: -10px;
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -10px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px, 10px);
  }

}

.bigTitle {
  font-size: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.Oswald {
  font-family: "Oswald";
}

.middleTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 43%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.rightTextHeader {
  margin-left: 3vh;
  margin-top: 1.5vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 8.5vh
}

.secondPage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000;
}

/* Here is our secondPage content */
.secondPage-para {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Purpl5Rain - Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/firstPage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/secondPage.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <p class="Oswald rightTextHeader">BeatMaker</p>
    </div>
    <div class="firstPage">
      <div class="middleTitle">
        <h1 class="bigTitle Oswald">PURPL5RAIN</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondPage">
      
<!-- add some content here to make seconds page visible. Without content, it'll show it's own height -->
      <p class="secondPage-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque fuga eligendi maiores porro quidem, consequuntur voluptatem fugit maxime neque eveniet iusto error voluptas quo tempore soluta autem omnis deleniti beatae.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Well, basically your `.secondPage` doesn't have any content to show up. That's the problem. But your `.secondPage` styles like `height`, `backgroud-color` are working properly as you can see. So `.secondPage` is actually showing, isn't it?

Just add some content here(actually you will have to add content in future, haven't you?) & you are ready to go.

#A bit Explanation -

By default, an element will show it's default height, if there are no content within it(that's why we use `overflow: hidden` in navigation to prevent it, if you have already worked with it!). And the default height is actually `0`. So it's doesn't show up, and we think our code is broken.

Let's go through a demonstration -

```css
.blue-div {
  background-color: #0a9dff;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-div">
</div>
```

As you can see here, nothing is actually showing. Because there is nothing to show(actually). But whenever we add a heading, it's showing the blue color as `background-color`.

```css
.blue-div {
  background-color: #0a9dff;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-div">
  <h3>Hello World!</h3>
</div>
```

See? Content is King!

So keep that in mind. This is something that'll help you *a lot* in CSS world!
Thank you :)

Comment: In this, you added extra css part to change the fonts color as white. I didn't do that. Instead of that, I change the background color. So both are same :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to visible the second page when the down arrow button clicked. If so then you need to apply js. Am I right? If I'm right then there has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the styling of the box, which hides the other page div. You may need to style the second-page div in view of the box styling.